# How to import 20000 records of a table in two different files (records equally distributed) if table does not have primary key or unique key?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I have 20000 records in a table. I want copy them to two separate files( records equally distributed) into HDFS (using Sqoop). 
How do we achieve this, if table does not have primary key or unique key?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are giving --split-by col1 with -m 2 else you will see an error.

Answer (score -1):

**Having primary key or unique key is not a limitation for importing parallelly.**

Splitting on non-uniformly distributed column in not recommended because this can result in unbalanced tasks.

Now your records are evenly distributed. So, there will not be any performance issue with this.

Let me explain it's working using an example,

You have a table with column `col1` with values from 1 -100 (*some of the repeated values are also there*).

Now, sqoop will determine minimum and maximum value and split it into 2 parts

- 1 - 50
- 51 - 100

Mappers will fetch data via JDBC using queries like -

- `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id >= 1 AND id < 50`
- `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id >= 51 AND id < 100`

So, go ahead with your sqoop import query with two mappers (`-m 2`).